# Запуск игры с рабочего стола JS

Tags: javascript, windows, click

Можно ли с помощью JS или же другого языка запустить определенный ярлык с рабочего стола Windows 10?

Например: Я хочу, чтобы при нажатие на кнопку в браузере запустилась -> "GTA Online".

Или это невозможно?

Comment: Возможно при наличии у пользователя локальной программы, ожидающей сообщений (команд) из браузерного расширения, передающихся через [специальный API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/nativeMessaging). Скриптом со страницы - невозможно.

Comment: Я видел как подобное использовалось в разных ПО, в том же дискорде, в том же скайпе, в стиме, из URL можно запустить программу. Вот пример https://i.imgur.com/UowyEfa.png

Answer (score 4):

Что Skype, что Discord не запускают ярлык с рабочего стола, а регистрируют собственный обработчик ссылки (протокол) в операционной системе. Если программа написана с применением библиотеки Qt, сделать это можно [так](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qdesktopservices.html#url-handlers).

Вот несколько распространенных протоколов, мне известных:

```
<a href="mailto:example@gmail.com">example@gmail.com</a>
<a href="tel:+74951111111">+7 (495) 111-11-11</a>
<a href="sms:12345678">SMS для 12345678</a>
<a href="skype://">Skype</a>
```